# Why does eclipse/maven does not always deploy my project with last update?

Tags: eclipse, maven, deployment, maven-tomcat-plugin

Here is my work environment: `Eclipse Juno` as `IDE` with `maven2` plugin on it - it uses `maven 3.0.4` installation from my system - and my `maven` web project is deployed to a remote server on an `Apace Tomcat` java server. (The server is in the same `LAN` with my machine.) Every thing works perfect, except some rare situations: it happens randomly.

**Problem**: At some times, when I try to redeploy my updated project to `Tomcat`, through `tomcat-maven-plugin`, the `JavaScript` files in the `Tomcat`'s project directory, DO NOT change. They stay intact (even if I did changes to them), and my application has lack in behavior. No errors are reported by `maven` during redeployment.

**Question**: do you have any idea about what's happening?

*N.B.*

1. In the rare situations when I got that problem, I got it working finally, after rebooting the `Tomcat` server, deleting the `Tomcat`'s project directory, cleaning `maven` installed artifact and other actions that I did - I just tried all what I could do, because I didn't have any logical clue for what happend.
2. I updated `Eclipse Galileo` to `Eclipse Juno` two days ago, and I encountered this problem in both of them. So, I think that's an issue rather related to `maven` not to `Eclipse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: I wasn't right when I said that the files are not updated on the server. My problem was the browser. It loads the `Javascript` file from cache. 
So `Ctrl`+`F5` resolved the problem.